# How can a Soliton be neutral in the Su-Schrieffer-Heeger (SSH) model when it carries an electron?

Tags: topological-insulators

I apologize if this is a trivial question. I am currently studying Girvin and Yang's book where they try to explain Spin-charge separation for the Solitons in the SSH model.

To my understanding, a Soliton in this case forms as an edge between two configurations that lead to the same energy (two-fold degenerate system). For certain limits, at least one of the electrons will lead to a zero mode due to the fact that the Hamiltonian is Chiral symmetric.

The book then makes a large jump (in my opinion) explaining that the Soliton is neutrally charged (Q=0) with spin 1/2. The spin-part makes sense since there is an electron present. I do, however, not understand how it can be neutral when it has a electron present.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: This paper:  https://pitp.phas.ubc.ca/confs/7pines2009/readings/jackiw-Topology.pdf gives a very simple counting argument for how to find the spin and charge on a soliton.

Answer (score 0):

In the presence of the solititon there is a ground-state fractional charge of $+e/2$ localized near the soliton for each of the spin-up and spin-down  Fermi seas: a total of $+e$. Adding an explicit electron in the mid-gap mode cancells this charge,leaving a neutral but spinful state.

Seeing how the ground-state charge is induced needs some math, but basically it is because 1/2 of the mid-gap state comes from the valance band and 1/2 from the conduction band.